# Data update tracking via application

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql, c#-4.0

I am in a strange problem, actually one of the developer developed an application in vb 5.0(or some same older but vb code) connected to sql server 2008 r2, and I don't have the source code of the application, but only the application.
Now my problem is that I don't know how the application is updating the tables in my database as the sql commands are written as part of the application not on database level like stored procedure or something. 
Now I got a job to make a web based/ desktop based app as we cant make any modification to an existing application(no source code available to us), just want to know is there any way that we can track/find out for a particular form of the existing application what changes(in which tables) its making when using it, so we can have the same functionality without breaking the existing application functionality.

appreciate if any solution provided.

Thanks

Comment: Yes. Use SQL Profiler to capture all of the SQL statements submitted to the database by the app.

Comment: thats the only way we have, I mean any other tool or something.

Comment: Are you asking if there is any other tool to capture the SQL Generated by an application? I'm sure there are but what's wrong with Profiler. Ifyou tell us what problem you have with it maybe we can suggest something suitable. BTW recommendations for tools is generally considered off topic here

Comment: because i dont have access to the sql profiler. Because one more app is using profiler and we are restricted to it.

Comment: You are replacing an application but you don't have access to SQL Profiler? What other constraints are there on this tool? Here are two more options: https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwifxuz3sa_SAhXlhlQKHUyaADsQFggZMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.brentozar.com%2Fresponder%2Flog-sp_whoisactive-to-a-table%2F&usg=AFQjCNHtICginMuOQYSmZV-olv2eWYWovA&sig2=82miM9BiROcOx1dWu2EkPA&bvm=bv.148073327,d.dGc&cad=rja https://jwcooney.com/2013/05/09/t-sql-get-a-historical-record-of-sql-statements-hitting-a-table/

Comment: I don't understand 'one more app is using sql profiler and we are restricted to it'. Is it a technical constraint or a political one (your boss says you can't)

Comment: No it doesn't mean that, the guy who created app left the company that time no one was aware of this and now he is not contactable. That time the user he gave was restricted to profiler.

Comment: I still don't get it. What happens when you go into your start menu and click on SQL Profiler? Can you log into the database using SSMS? Do you have SQL Tools installed? I am coming at this from a database perspective, but a programmer might have some ideas from another perspective (reflection?)

Comment: Yes i have sql login and can access database from ssms. But when i try to access profiler it says that you are not allowed to access it.

Comment: What is the text of the actual full error? Does it happen when you click the link or does it happen when you try and connect to the database from inside  it?

Comment: in order to access you must be a member of the sysadmin.......

Comment: So why not make yourself a member of sysadmin? Do you have a database where no one has sysadmin access?

Comment: Yes the sysadmin pwd we dont have

Comment: You've got a bigger problem than reverse engineering an app then. I suggest you recover sysadmin control by either engaging a DBA or following these instructions: https://sqlserver-help.com/2012/02/08/help-i-lost-sa-password-and-no-one-has-system-administrator-sysadmin-permission-what-should-i-do/

Comment: Ok. So there's no alternate to this.

Comment: Without sysadmin access your options are limited. In future please be more specific. Me providing you all this info was clearly a waste of time

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks alot for your help